# OOP login/register system

Tags: php, mysql, oop, authentication

I have another problem with login.php if I want to login and I have the 'remember me' butoon checken everything works fine. But when i have it unchecked i get this error.

I'm new to php and i use this system for a minor course so i know it is already old but i would really like to finish it i'm learning allot this way.

Notice: Undefined variable: hashCheck in C:\wamp\www\websitegroop\classes">" \user.php on line 63
Call Stack

1   0.0006  255552  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0
2   0.0094  386832  User->login( )  ..\login.php:25

and:

Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\websitegroop\classes\user.php on line 63
Call Stack

1   0.0006  255552  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0
2   0.0094  386832  User->login( )  ..\login.php:25

Here is my code:

login.php

```
 enter code here <?php
                 require_once 'core/init.php';


                  if(Session::exists('login')) {
                  echo '<p>' . Session::flash('login') . '<p>';
                   }

                  if(Input::exists()) {
                  if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'gebruikersnaam' => array('required' => true),
        'paswoord' => array('required' => true)

    ));



    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $remember =(Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true: false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('gebruikersnaam'),              Input::get('paswoord'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('index.php');
        } else {
            echo '<p> Sorry het is niet gelukt om in te loggen. </p>';
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
}

}
?>
```

hash.php

```
enter code here  <?php
 class Hash {
public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
    return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
}

public static function salt($length) {
    return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
}

public static function unique() {
    return self::make(uniqid());

}
}
```

user.php

```
enter code here <?php


class User {
private $_db,
        $_data,
        $_sessionName,
        $_cookieName,
        $_isLoggedIn;       

public function __construct($user = null) {
    $this->_db = Database::getInstance();

    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

    if(!$user) {
        if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

            if($this->find($user)) {
                $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {

            }
        } else {
    }       $this->find($user);
   }
  }

public function create($fields = array()) {
    if(!$this->_db->insert('groopklanten', $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('Er is een probleem met het maken van een  account.');
    }

}

public function find($user = null) {
    if($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'gebruikersnaam';
        $data = $this->_db->get('groopklanten', array($field, '=',     $user));

        if($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function login($gebruikersnaam = null, $paswoord = null, $remember) {
    $user = $this->find($gebruikersnaam);

    if($user) {
        if($this->data()->paswoord === Hash::make($paswoord, $this->data()->salt)) { 
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

            if($remember) {
                $hash = Hash::unique();
                $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session_table', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));              }

                if(!$hashCheck->count()) {
                    $this->_db->insert('users_session_table', array(
                        'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                        'hash' => $hash
                    ));
                } else {
                    $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                }
                Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash,                 Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));

            }


            return true;

    }

    return false;
}

public function logout() {
    Session::delete($this->_sessionName);   
}

public function data() {
    return $this->_data;
}

public function isLoggedIn() {
    return $this->_isLoggedIn;  
}
 }
```

init.php

```
enter code here <?php
       session_start();

     $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'nick16061983',
        'password' => 'N1sn0p1!A',
        'db' => 'websitegroop'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),  
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'groopklanten',
        'token_name' => 'token'

    )
   );

   spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
   require_once 'classes/' .$class. '.php';
   });

  require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

I hope i have provided enough information.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at the error is states that you can't call count() on a non-object in user.php. From the looks of it you are calling the count function on the $hashCheck variable. This makes me think that $hashCheck is not being set sometimes. This may be due to the stray ending curly brace "}" on the following line:

```
$hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session_table', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));              }
```

That closing curly brace is actually causing it to think that the if statement block for the $remember variable ends on that line and instead of where you meant that block to end. See if removing that extra closing curly braces helps in regards to the syntax errors.

Comment: omg i completly overlooked that curly brace ...... thanks allot ill remember next time that i have to use the slider to check if there is something there ....

Answer (score 0):

The $remember variable always have true value, although you have not checked it. You must ensure that:

`$remember =(Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true: false;`

is valid. Or you can try reserve validation logic like this:

`$remember =(Input::get('remember') != '') ? true: false;`

Comment: thanks for the fast reply i have tried this but it gave me the same errors.

Comment: or change to casual if/else:

if (empty(Input::get('remember'))) {$remember=True} else {$remember=false}

Comment: I get syntax errors and im new to PHP so i tried some things but the syntax error remains.